# Box2D wrong body rotation

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, tiled

I making a map with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) and load all box2d bodies with [Box2DMapObjectParser](https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/net.dermetfan.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DMapObjectParser) to my world and everything just work fine except one thing. I'm using a newer version of Tiled where implemented body rotation. I'm trying to implement it in Box2DMapObjectParser by myself and this is what I get from it:

Editor:
[image]

And the game:
[image]

As you can see the right rectangle has a property named Rotation so I can easily get from properties, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

I set the rotation like this

```
fixture.getBody().setTransform(fixture.getBody().getPosition(), degree);
```

where `degree` is value from editor. Anybody have a clues about what am I doing wrong? I also tried doing something like

```
fixture.getBody().setTransform(fixture.getBody().getPosition(), degree*MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
```

But itsalso sets a wrong rotation.

Comment: use -degree*MathUtills.degreetoradian

Comment: I tried it and it did not help. Looks like the editor rotates body from it's center and box2d `setTransform` rotates it from bottom left corner. is there a way to rotate it like editor does?

Comment: @BeforeBigBang Can you please share your solution? I'm having the same issue and I can't figure out what is suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: @LiorIluz Sorry mate, it's been so long since i did this, i don't have src anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiled rotates rectangle objects by their top-left corner. Box2D rotates around the position of the body, so the easiest solution is probably to create your box fixture such that the position of the body is in the top-left (if you're using `b2PolygonShape::SetAsBox` this means passing a center at half the width and half the negative height (since the Y axis is inverted)).